# AWS - Heroku - Ruby on Rails - Failed to install gems via Bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, aws-cloud9

I am running bundle update in the AWS environment but I am getting an error:

An error occurred while installing pg (0.20.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.20.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

I am following the [this tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning%20tutorial). When I run `git push Heroku master` , it says it `failed to install gems via bundler`.

Im not sure why I cannot install the gems needed.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: In your aws environment can you try `sudo apt-get install postgresql-client libpq5 libpq-dev`, which installs the libraries and dependencies required for postgresql, then try `bundle update`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know but i think you should run this step before bundling

gem install pg

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to deploy to AWS or Heroku?

**If it's Heroku:**

The pg version's that Heroku uses is: 0.21.0

So, you should put into your Gemfile:

```
gem 'pg', '0.21.0'
```

And then commit and push to Heroku

**If it's AWS:**

You should try just as @Kumar commented on your post...